# Por que mi función me devuelve NaN

Tags: javascript

Mi función me devuelve un NaN y no debería. lo que debería hacer es calcular el precio de un producto con un descuento y el descuento de un cupón el cual ya fue declarado. La función que calcula el primer descuento con una regla de tres funciona bien pero la función `onClickDescuentoCupon` me devuelve un NaN y no sé por qué:

```
function calcularPrecioConDescuento(precio, descuento){ //calcula con una regla de tres el descuento

       const porcentajeDescuento = 100 - descuento;
       const precioConDescuento  = (porcentajeDescuento * precio)/100
       return precioConDescuento
}

function onClickButtonPriceDiscount(){ //imprime en html la función anterior
     const inputPrice    = document.getElementById('inputPrice');
     const priceValue    = inputPrice.value; 

     const inputDiscount = document.getElementById('inputDiscount');
     const discountValue = inputDiscount.value;

     const precioFinal = calcularPrecioConDescuento(priceValue, discountValue);
     const resultP     = document.getElementById('ResultP');
     resultP.innerText = 'Tu descuento es de: ' + precioFinal + '%';
}

const cupones = ['ANA ', ' ES ', ' UNA ', ' AVENGER '];
function CuponesTiendaVirtualResultado(){ //muestra los cupones disponibles en la tienda virtual
     const resultadoCuponesDisponibles = document.getElementById('CuponesD');
     resultadoCuponesDisponibles.innerHTML = 'los cupones disponibles en la tienda son: ' + cupones;
}

function onClickDescuentoCupon(){

     const inputPrice    = document.getElementById('inputPrice');
     const priceValue    = inputPrice.value; 

     const inputCupon    = document.getElementById('inputCupon');
     const valueCupon    = inputCupon.value; 

     let descuento;
     switch(valueCupon){
          case cupones[0]:
               descuento = 20;
          break;
          case cupones[1]:
               descuento = 15;
          break;
          case cupones[2]:
               descuento = 50;
          break;
          case cupones[3]:
               descuento = 60;     
     }

const precioConDescuentoCupones = calcularPrecioConDescuento(priceValue, descuento);
const resultadoDC     = document.getElementById('resultadoDC');
resultadoDC.innerHTML = 'el precio final de tu producto es de $ ' + precioConDescuentoCupones;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- En la función calcularPrecioConDescuento faltaban los punto-y-coma finales de 2  líneas

2.- En la función onClickDescuentoCupon te ha faltado poner un break en el último caso

3.- Intenta usar comillas dobles para insertar texto en los inputs de funciones

Aquí esta el código:

```
function calcularPrecioConDescuento(precio, descuento){ //aca faltaba punto y coma

   const porcentajeDescuento = 100 - descuento;
   const precioConDescuento  = (porcentajeDescuento * precio)/100;
   return precioConDescuento;
}

function onClickButtonPriceDiscount(){ //imprime en html la función anterior
 const inputPrice    = document.getElementById("inputPrice");
 const priceValue    = inputPrice.value; 

 const inputDiscount = document.getElementById("inputDiscount");
 const discountValue = inputDiscount.value;

 const precioFinal = calcularPrecioConDescuento(priceValue, discountValue);
 const resultP     = document.getElementById("ResultP");
 resultP.innerText = "Tu descuento es de: " + precioFinal + "%";
}

const cupones = ['ANA ', ' ES ', ' UNA ', ' AVENGER '];
function CuponesTiendaVirtualResultado(){ //muestra los cupones disponibles en la tienda virtual
 const resultadoCuponesDisponibles = document.getElementById("CuponesD");
 resultadoCuponesDisponibles.innerHTML = "los cupones disponibles en la tienda son: " + cupones;
}

function onClickDescuentoCupon(){

 const inputPrice    = document.getElementById("inputPrice");
 const priceValue    = inputPrice.value; 

 const inputCupon    = document.getElementById("inputCupon");
 const valueCupon    = inputCupon.value; 

 let descuento;
 switch(valueCupon){
      case cupones[0]:
           descuento = 20;
      break;
      case cupones[1]:
           descuento = 15;
      break;
      case cupones[2]:
           descuento = 50;
      break;
      case cupones[3]:
           descuento = 60;
        break;     
 }

 const precioConDescuentoCupones = calcularPrecioConDescuento(priceValue, descuento);
 const resultadoDC     = document.getElementById("resultadoDC");
 resultadoDC.innerHTML = "el precio final de tu producto es de $ " + precioConDescuentoCupones;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Como bien dice @mishrole, el problema es que si no se cumple ninguna de las opciones del switch, la variable descuento que has declarado con `let descuento;` tiene un valor de "undefined", cuando esa variable la envías a la función calcularPrecioConDescuento, siempre te devolverá NaN. Para evitar eso, declárala con valor 0 y si alguna opción se cumple en el switch ya le cambiará el valor, pero si no se cumple ninguna, tendrá un valor de 0 y no te dará error al realizar un cálculo con ella. `let descuento = 0;`
Un saludo!!

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que el valor de **valueCupon** no sea ninguno de los posibles valores del arreglo **cupones** cuando se llama a la función **onClickDescuentoCupon**. Según este arreglo, los cupones válidos son:

- ANA  en mayúsculas y con un espacio al final
- ES  en mayúsculas y con un espacio antes y después
- UNA  en mayúsculas y con un espacio antes y después
- AVENGER  en mayúsculas y con un espacio antes y después

De este modo, cuando llega al switch, **valueCupon** no cumple con ninguno de los casos y el resultado es NaN. Si añades un caso *default*, dejará de darte NaN, pero siempre entrará a ese caso a menos que el cupón sea ingresado tal cual se encuentra en el arreglo.

A menos que sea obligatorio que el cupón cuente con estos espacios, sugiero los remuevas en el arreglo, dado que los cupones generalmente no contienen espacios; también es recomendable que controles posibles espacios de más en el input#inputCupon utilizando [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

En **onClickDescuentoCupon()**, valueCupon quedaría así:

```
const valueCupon = inputCupon.value.trim();
```

Y el arreglo **cupones** quedaría así:

```
const cupones = ['ANA', 'ES', 'UNA', 'AVENGER'];
```